# How to filter data inside Flatlist on React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I've been working on this app and so far I managed to Upload and retrieve data from a server, but right now i'm struggling on showing the data inside a Flatlist.

```js
 <View>
  <FlatList
   data={recibidos}
   style={styles.verTres}
   renderItem={({item}) => (
     <View>
     <Text style={styles.chatContent}>Mensaje: {item.mensaje}</Text>
     <Image source={{uri: 'http://api-url/'+item.mensaje}} style={styles.imageView}/>
     <Video source={{uri: 'http://api-url/'+item.mensaje}} style={styles.imageView}/>
     </View>                
    )}
   keyExtractor={item => item.mensaje}
   />
  </View>
```

So this is the code i wrote to show the responses i get from the server, the problem with this is that the `renderItem` function render everything as Text, Image and Video no matter what and it looks like this.
[image: Screenshot]
[image: Distance between responses]
[image: Uri text]

So my question is, how to filter the response as text, video or image if is only one for everything and it looks like this:

For Text

```
{"id":"112","nombre":null,"mensaje":"Hola","fecha":"2020-09-18
15:46:21","estado":"0"}
```

For Image

```
{"id":"113","nombre":null,"mensaje":"resource\/img_4820200918154854.logo_small","fecha":"2020-09-18
15:48:54","estado":"0"}
```

For Video

```
{"id":"133","nombre":null,"mensaje":"resource\/video_4820201001080513.","fecha":"2020-10-01
08:05:13","estado":"0"}
```

But as I mentioned, the response come from only one method.

I tried to use an `if` statement inside my renderItem as I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58991451/react-native-render-flatlist-conditional), but that didn't work.

I would appreciate any help or advice you could give me

Comment: So the value of `mensaje` can be Text or img or vid?

Comment: @OliverD yes, that is my response.

Comment: Another q, now in this img https://i.stack.imgur.com/F50Xe.jpg when u return mensaje it returns path with extension .png but in the response above For Image section dose not include it so what's the difference? And if you can share ur code in snack.expo.io well helped more ;)

Comment: That´s only the name of the resource, the guy that made the service did a lot of weird things.

Comment: I feel u, what in my mind when you got the data and render it make an conditions to check mensaje like this way mensaje.endsWith(".png")? <Image /> : mensaje.endsWith(".mp4")? <Video />  : <Text/>

Comment: you can check by mensage.includes('video') for video or mensage.includes('img') for image as I see in response mensage field has video and img string respectively